# Forward compatability issues in alert dialog for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an issue with an Alert dialog for Android 2.3.3 HTC Desire HD.

#### Create list view to display items

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> lst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < m_lstSettings.size(); i++)
    lst.add( new HashMap<String,String>());

// While we are setting a list adapter, we are only using it to hold the
// structure of the list.  We will actually override its data in getView()
// before displaying it.
setListAdapter(
    new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        lst,
        R.layout.settings_row,
        new String[] { "text1","text2" },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
   ) {
        /**
        * Override for the getView() method.  This allows us to alter the display
        * attributes on a line-by-line basis.  We also use this opportunity to
        * fill in the text fields with the right values.
        */
        @Override
        public View getView(int iPos, View oConvertView, ViewGroup oParent)
        {
            // Fetch list item based on position
            ListItem oItem = m_lstSettings.get(iPos);

            // create view for this row from xml layout file
            View oView = m_oInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_row, null); 

            // for some reason, the logic in this method call seems to be reversed,
            // but it works this way
            oView.setClickable(oItem.m_bLocked); 

            // set up the label text view
            TextView tvLabel = (TextView) oView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if (tvLabel != null)
            {
                tvLabel.setText(oItem.m_sLabel);
                tvLabel.setEnabled(!oItem.m_bLocked);
            }

            // set up the value text view
            TextView tvValue = (TextView) oView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

            if (tvValue != null) {
                tvValue.setText(oItem.m_sValue);
                tvValue.setEnabled(!oItem.m_bLocked);
            }
        }

        return oView;
    }
}
);
```

```
/**
* Click handler for the list items.  Will create the appropriate edit 
* box for the clicked setting.
*/
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView oParent, View v, int iPos, long id)
{
    // inflate the xml layout
    final View oView = m_oInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_edit, null);
    final ListView oParentListView = oParent;
    final SettingsListItem oItem = m_lstSettings.get(iPos);

    // set label
    TextView tv = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewEditSettings);
    if (tv != null)
        tv.setText(oItem.m_sLabel);

    // set value
    tv = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextEditSettings);
    if (tv != null) {
        tv.setText(oItem.m_sValue);
        tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }


    // special input validator for integers
    if (oItem.m_bTypeInt)
        tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    userName = m_lstSettings.get(3).m_sValue;

    // show dialog
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.Label_Edit) + " " + oItem.m_sLabel)
        .setView(oView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.main_connection_button_ok_button,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextEditSettings);
                    oItem.m_sValue = tv.getText().toString(); 

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tv.getWindowToken(), 0);



                    oParentListView.invalidate();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextEditSettings);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tv.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
        .show();

}
```

XML files:

#### `settings_row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"

    android:background="@color/message_list_item_background"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### `settings_edit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/TextViewEditSettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEditSettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using the above code first we create the list view and upon clicking each item it displays an alert dialog to enter input.

We have 6 items in the list. Upon clicking the 4th item, the app crashes. It's reproducible only on the HTC Desire HD. App is working fine on other Android 2.3 devices, such as Google Nexus S and Sony Ericsson Arc.

Comment: Can you add a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: Add a stack trace for the crash, or we can't help you.